# How to integrate a multi select list with dform like SelectOneMenu of primefaces?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, multi-select

I have created a form using dform library. Now i have to add a multiple select
list like that of primefaces. As far as i have read dform doesnt support multi
selecting. I have done some research, and also have tried to integrate some jquery plugins but still no luck. Can someone suggest me how to find a solution please?

```
field : 'otherResources', type : 'multipleSelect', class : 'selectpicker', caption : LANGUAGE.tryToTranslate('otherResources'), options : { 'us' : 'USA', 'de' : 'German' }


$.dform.addType("multipleSelect", function(options) {
     var r = $("<select multiple>").dform('attr', options); 
     return r; 
});
```

Comment: Please share your code..

Comment: Here i have tried to integrate with bootstrap multi select. Here is the type definition

Comment: $.dform.addType("multipleSelect", function(options) {
  var r =  $("<select multiple>").dform('attr', options);  
  return r;
 });

Comment: here i have defined the form

Comment: field : 'otherResources',
    type : 'multipleSelect',
    class : 'selectpicker',
    caption : LANGUAGE.tryToTranslate('otherResources'),
    options : {
     'us' : 'USA',
     'de' : 'German'
    }

Comment: Pikachu, do you understand what i am trying to do?